# count and sum from different table

Tags: mysql, sql

Help! how can I count  and sum the agents transaction from the different table.
on the agent seller table each of transaction are already sold by agent, by each agent count and sum . mike $1800.00 and ray $400.00. How can do this on sql?

I only want 1 agent to be displayed.. Mike

Mike sold item = 4

TOtal of mike revenue = $1800

ray sold item = 2

Total of ray revenue = $400

sorry for my bad english

```
price table
-----------------------------------------
|  comics |  type   | price   |comic_id  |
|----------------------------------------|
|comic1   | sci-fi  | $500.00 |   1      |
|comic2   | History | $200.00 |   2      |
|comic3   | Horror  | $350.00 |   3      |
-----------------------------------------


Agent seller Table
----------------------------------------------- 
|Agent| transaction_id| datesold   | comic_id |
-----------------------------------------------
|mike | 93847534eara33| 2020-00-01 |    1     |
|mike | 933sdf34eara33| 2020-00-01 |    3     |
|mike | 4ssffss4eara33| 2020-00-01 |    1     |
|mike | efeaf334aafafa| 2020-00-02 |    1     |
|ray  | 4223r3qraa4322| 2020-00-01 |    2     |
|ray  | aerar3qraa4322| 2020-00-01 |    2     |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Also, what you describe seems to be a simple `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okay mate.. sorry for bad english its not my language.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Also, don't store '$' - at least not in the same column as price

Answer (score 0):

Considering the table structure as below:

```
price table
-----------------------------------------
|  comics |  type   | price   |comic_id  |
|----------------------------------------|
|comic1   | sci-fi  | $500.00 |   1      |
|comic2   | History | $200.00 |   2      |
|comic3   | Horror  | $350.00 |   3      |
-----------------------------------------


Agent seller Table
----------------------------------------------- 
|Agent| transaction_id| datesold   | comic_id |
-----------------------------------------------
|mike | 93847534eara33| 2020-00-01 |    1     |
|mike | 933sdf34eara33| 2020-00-01 |    3     |
|mike | 4ssffss4eara33| 2020-00-01 |    1     |
|mike | efeaf334aafafa| 2020-00-02 |    1     |
|ray  | 4223r3qraa4322| 2020-00-01 |    2     |
|ray  | aerar3qraa4322| 2020-00-01 |    2     |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Here's what your query will look like:

```
SELECT Agent, sum(price) as total_agent_revenue, count(comics) as sold_item_count 
FROM price 
JOIN agent on price.comic_id = agent.comic_id
GROUP BY Agent
```

Result:

[image: sql result]